# What's the connotation of saying "You are absorbed in things"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was talking to a girl, and her mother is in the hospital. I asked her how her mom is doing, her and her family. No reply for a week. Then I sent her another message saying

> I guess you are absorbed in things (not kidnapped:) ), msg me if you want to hang out again.

My American friend told me that I shouldn't have used the word "absorbed", because it has a meaning of being selfish, self-centered, which makes her feel bad. Is that true? Did I just mess up the text message?

Comment: Just like *preoccupied* or *distracted*, *absorbed* doesn't necessarily convey that she is "selfish, self-centered"; it merely conveys that she has had other priorities. But depending on the severity of her mother's condition, it might not have been sensitive to her situation.

Comment: That would imply something like, *This situation has taken up your attention completely.* So, I wouldn't give a negative connotation to your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Merriam-Webster's definition of [**absorbed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absorbed):

> : having one's attention wholly engaged or occupied

It has nothing to do with being selfish or self-centred.

---

Perhaps your friend was thinking of [**self-absorbed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-absorbed) (also from Merriam-Webster):

> : absorbed in one's own thoughts, activities, or interests

The two have different meanings and should not be confused with each other.